# The infamous tabs or spaces

Tags: discussion, markdown

Is there a standard for code formatting within the Stack Exchange network? I have noticed on other sites they use tabs by default. On this site, is there a default tabs to spaces?

Comment: We don't prescribe or enforce coding-style, so keep your hand off my tabs.

Comment: Also not sure why [Cooking.se](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) should use tabs ... or spaces for that matter.

Comment: @rene Tabs are superior why do some people smash their space bar 4 times inserted of pressing the tab key once? It just seems slightly ludicrous :)

Comment: It is because [they make more money](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Markdown editor does not touch the code one is posting. It does not change spaces to tabs and does not change tabs to spaces.

When selecting a code block and clicking the code sample editor button, it just inserts four spaces in the beginning of each selected line, nothing more.

In the final output, it doesn't really matter if tabs or spaces were used. These days modern browsers will show it exactly the same as far as I can tell.